# Indexing a NumPy array like a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I need to use a two-dimensional NumPy array for performance reasons, but I also need to be able to index each element. The indices would be `models1` and `models2` which subclasses of `django.db.models.Model`.

I need to be able to get and set items, slice and pass lists of indices, filter, and so on, just as if it were a regular NumPy with integer indices. But I also need to be able to do this using the mentioned indices.

Examples of operations I should be able to do:

```
arr[m1]
arr[:,m2]
arr[(0,1,4),:] = N
```

Is there a standarized way to index NumPy arrays? I haven't been able to find one yet.

I have tried this:

```
class IndexedArray:
    def __init__(self, models1, models2):
        self.shape = (len(models1), len(models2))
        self.arr = np.full(self.shape, 1)
        self.models1 = [m1 for m1 in models1]
        self.models2 = [m2 for m2 in models2]
        self.model1_indices = {m1: i for i, m1 in enumerate(self.models1)}
        self.model2_indices = {m2: i for i, m2 in enumerate(self.models2)}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            i = self.models1_indices[key[0]]
            j = self.models2_indices[key[1]]
            self.arr[i, j] = value
        else:
            i = self.models1_indices[key]
            self.arr[i] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            i = self.models1_indices[key[0]]
            j = self.models2_indices[key[1]]
            return self.arr[i, j]
        i = self.models1_indices[key]
        return self.arr[i]

    def get_index(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Model1):
            return self.models1_indices[o]
        if isinstance(o, Model2):
            return self.models2_indices[o]
        raise TypeError
```

But the number of available operations are limited. I can only get and set `arr[m1,m2]`, `arr[m1]` but not `arr[:,m2]` because slices are not supported (not that they would make sense, but then how can I mass-assign to the second dimension? What should I pass as first index?), and that's about it. Filtering is not supported either...

Comment: Could you use Pandas instead of doing it from scratch ? You may as well find useful resource in their source code.

Comment: @Arius I actually used a `DataFrame` at first, but ditched it in favor of NumPy because performance is critical.

Comment: Why don't you subclass `np.ndarray`. It's explained here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html . Then you could overload `__new__`, `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`.

Comment: The only way I know to mimic dictionaries is using a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), but that only allows to use strings as indices, so the idea @FHTMitchell is probably best.

Comment: What's `m1` and `m2`?  Variables with integer (or list, array or slice) values?  Or strings?  Or more complex hashable values?  How about setting up a dictionary or function that maps these values onto the simple indices that `ndarray` can use?

Comment: If `m1` is a tuple, it can be used to index and/or slice a multidimensional array: `m1 = (slice(None), 1); x[m1]`

Comment: @hpaulj as I mentioned they would be instances of Django model subclasses. So they have integer IDs, but how would I map them to indices?

Comment: Look at the code in `np.lib.index_tricks.py` to see how to construct complex `__getitem__` methods.

Comment: @FHTMitchell I have been trying to look at your suggestion, but I am not sure how to go about it. Wouldn't the overridden methods be pretty much what I shows in my original post? Essentially all I'd need is to map my objects indices to integer indices right?

Comment: @hpaulj I have been trying to make some sense of `np.lib.index_tricks.py` but all examples seem pretty complex. What do you suggest I should do to subclass `ndarray`? What should I override and how?

Comment: @dabadaba yup... Use the answer below to convert model keys into numpy integer / slice keys.

Comment: @FHTMitchell well that's exactly what I was doing to begin with wasn't I? But am I supposed to override `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` or just use the mapper to access the `ndarray` directly? Another problem: if I were to subclass `ndarray`, since I am supposed to override `__new__` and this is a class method, where am I to store `self.models1_indices` and `self.models2_indices`?

Comment: At some point in `__new__`, you create an instance using `super().__new__(cls, *args)`. Instead of returning right away you can assign it to a variable (e..g `self`) and then assign attributes to that `self.a = b` or whatever before `return self`.

Comment: `recarray` is another instructive subclass.

Comment: @FHTMitchell alright so I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/kpagcha/afbe8c399c7fdce0de65acb62d899a02) however weirdly enough when trying to set a value `arr = IndexedArray(models1, models2); arr[m1, m2] = N;` for some **weird** reason while `key` should be `(m1, m2)`, it is magically transformed to `(0, 0)` by `__setitem__`. What's happening here?

Comment: if you use a dubugger / print, what are `i, j` in `__setitem__`? Also what is `self.arr`? Don't you mean `super().__setitem__((i, j))`? You also never `return` from `__new__`. This will fail at runtime. I think you need to go back and read the subclassing `ndarray` page I linked. If it is beyond you, I'd go back and rethink your strategy.

Comment: @FHTMitchell `i, j` would be nothing because the execution fails when trying to do `key[0]` since `key` appears to be a tuple of integers instead of a tuple of `(model1, model2)` which is what I expect from `arr[m1, m2]`. About `self.arr` and returning from `__new__`, my bad when copying the code, check out the [updated snippet.](https://gist.github.com/kpagcha/afbe8c399c7fdce0de65acb62d899a02)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, you wanna be able to give Models keys as well as their index in the dicts `modelX_indices` ?

This is how I would approach the problem:

- If the key parameter was a tuple or list, we treat each entry inside as a separate key to convert it to int.
- If the key is a slice, we don't touch it*.
- If the key is a Model, we convert it to an int, and don't touch it if it's already an int.

The following function does this work:

```
def key_to_int(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, (tuple, list)):
        return tuple(key_to_int(k) for k in key)
    if isinstance(key, Model1):
        return self.models1_indices[key]
    if isinstance(key, Model2):
        return self.models2_indices[key]
    return key
```

*: Except if you have a sense for slicing with Models ?

Comment: How would you use `key_to_int`? You are suggseting I shouldn't sublcass at all, just use a regular `np.ndarray` and every time I access it I need to map `models1` or `models2` to int?

Comment: No, `key_to_int` is an attribute of the class you akready wrote. In fact you could put the code in your `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, but there would be duplating code, that’s why i’d write a function.